# hashmap resultmap in mybatis

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, mybatis

I have a java class like this:

```
public class Team {
private HashMap<String, User> users;
private int id_team;
private String nome;
...
}
```

And an xml file like this:

```
<resultMap id="userJoinTeamResultMap" type="Team">
    <id column="id_team" property="id_team" />
    <result column="nome" property="nome" />
    <collection property="users" javaType="HashMap" >
        <id column="id_user" property="id" />
        <result column="nome_user" property="nome" />
        <result column="cognome" property="cognome" />
        <result column="email" property="email" />
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

And a select that does what it have to do. 
But when I try to get the values in my hashmap:

```
ArrayList<Team> listaTeam = getBlmTeam().getUserTeamFromCorso(jsonInput.getInt("id_corso"));
Iterator<Team> it = listaTeam.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
        Team t = it.next();
        Collection<String> set = t.getUsers().keySet();
        Iterator it2 = set.iterator();
        while(it2.hasNext()){
             Object k = it2.next();
             System.out.println("key:"+k.toString()+"  value:"+t.getUsers().get(k));
}}
```

My values are:

```
key:id     value:103
key:email  value:HSXB736GB
key:id     value:105
key:email  value:ZQFD4U
..
```

What keys are???
In the first team there are two users with keys 102 and 103. But every user uses the key "id", so, they are overwritten.

Comment: What is Utente class ?

Comment: t.getUsers().get(k) is a `User`, how could it print sometimes 103 (id), sometimes HSXB736GB (email ?). Could you show us User source code ?

Comment: I don't know why! Keys and values are wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved using

```
private Arraylist<User> users;
```

and

```
<collection property="users" javaType="ArrayList">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the `HashMap` correctly. You don't want to map

```
id -> 103
email -> HSXB736GB
```

etc. As you've discovered, if you do that, you'll only be able to have one user in there, because the key has to be unique, so when you add a new user, the `id` will be overwritten.

What you want to do is to map IDs to user objects

```
103 -> [user instance with ID 103]
105 -> [user instance with ID 105]
```

This means that rather than `HashMap<String,Utente>` you want `HashMap<Integer,Utente>`. Then you can do things like

```
Utente someUser = ...
map.put(someUser.getId(), someUser);
```

and later you'll be able to retrieve the user from the map with

```
Utente someUser = map.get(id);
```

as long as you know the ID.

Comment: I changed to integer, but the result is the same.

Comment: You need to do more than that: you also need to change what you're using as the key. Don't use `"id"` as the key: use the id itself.

Comment: yes, thank you. My problem is how to do that. I thought my ResultMap was right.